# Windsor XML configuration of generics

Tags: xml, generics, configuration, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

How do i setup the configuration in XML (for Windsor Castle) for the following class?

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
....
}
```

I know how to do it in code but i must use XML file

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<component id="repository"
   service="MyNamespace.IRepository`1, MyAssembly"
   type="MyNamespace.Repository`1, MyAssembly"/>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Mauricio! Works as expected!